# EF 4.0 to EF 4.2 , DeleteObject Not Found,

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, migration

My original project is in Asp.net MVC 2.
I convert my project to MVC 3 without problem.

In the same time, I install the EntityFramework 4.2. Again without problem.

Were it's begin to be complicated is when I add the T4 Generate DBContext. 
Thats create me the T4 properly and generate all my entity into his own "POCO Class". Thats perfect!.

When I Build my project, I Got about 400 error. Here is some example.

> 'mvn.Models.DBEntities' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddToLeaseConditionInfos' and no extension method
>   'AddToLeaseConditionInfos' accepting a first argument of type
>   'mvn.Models.DBEntities' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

As you can see here, the context.AddToLeaseConditionInfos(objCondition); doesn't work anymore.

Same for the DeleteObject context method.

> context.ConvertionUnits.DeleteObject(MyObjConvertionUnit);

Someone has an Idea.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: EF 4.2 is just EF 4.1 with few bug fixes. It doesn't need its own tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You previously used ObjectContext API and default code generator (or EntityObject T4 template) but now you are trying to use DbContext API with POCO DbContext T4 Generator. Those two are completely incompatible because they represent different API. You must use the same code generation approach as you used in EFv4 (which means upgrade will not give you almost any additional value) or you must rewrite your current data access code to use new API.

Comment: Is there any performance benefit to change to DBContext API instead of using the default ObjectContext API. I Got 270 Entities and I Got many Relation between each of them. The compile time is Very long. I Have big query too that make my project very slow for some modules or pages .

Comment: DbContext API is just simplified wrapper around ObjectContext API so theoretically the performance can be even little bit worse because of additional level of wrapping code.